# How to use mediainfo see video file information on aws s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mediainfo

I have installed mediainfo tool on mac. I can use it see local video file. But when I see a information about which file on aws s3, I got an error:

```
$ mediainfo "https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/my/folder/my-video.wmv\?AWSAccessKeyId\=MyKeyId\&Expires\=298838448\&Signature\=sf389h94nvshgohwogwdn"
E: https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/my/folder/my-video.wmv\?AWSAccessKeyId\=MyKeyId\&Expires\=298838448\&Signature\=sf389h94nvshgohwogwdn, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message> <RequestId>FOI2IFNFEFI3F</RequestId><HostId>ofoiheoHAOI3hf2048hHlhfhldnlsx9ajldkfahssflflweiwf3ivnv</HostId></Error>
```

I can access that video from public url, but why can't access from `mediainfo`?

Comment: What's going on with all of the backslashes?  Enclose the URL in single `'` quotes and you don't have to escape anything.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you very much! You are right! When I changed `"` to `'` and moved all the backslashes, it works fine! Would you like write it down as an answer and I will accept it.